# How to implement an object cache with weak references (in Typescript)

Tags: typescript

I have a set of classes that are to be used with *equality by value*. Many instances of the class will be created but most of them are logically equal. For these classes, I want to develop a cache that retains objects only until there is no strong reference to the objects outside of the cache.

More concretely, I have an object model for structured schemas. A schema, among many other things, contains attributes, each with a type. Many attributes will be identical. For instance, there are many attributes `id: number`. Without caching, I am creating many copies of these objects like `attribute("id", type("number"))` where `attribute` and `type` are factory functions (see code below). So, what I am trying to do is implement a general object cache that allows me to "intern" objects so that always the same instance is returned by the factory for the same inputs.

Here is an example:

```
export function attributeDefinition(
  name: string,
  type: AttributeType
): AttributeDefinition {
  const def = new AttributeDefinition(name, type);
  return OBJECT_CACHE.intern(def);
}
```

The object cache will check in a map whether the object already exists and, on a hit, will return that cached copy, basically, using the input `def` as just a key. On a miss, it will cache the input and return it. So far so good, this apparently behaves as desired. However, the object cache now is a potential memory leak as it keeps adding references to objects which it never removes. The solution that I know from other languages would be to use a `WeakMap` and wrap values into `WeakRef`. Then, the garbage collector automatically removes objects from the cache that are not strongly referenced outside the cache.

Unfortunately, the typescript `WeakMap` only accepts objects as keys. This would be fine if there where `equals` and `hashCode` that I could override to resemble logical equality. However, as it is, objects are only equal if they are identical by reference.

If the `WeakMap` *would* accept `string` as key, then I *could* maintain a strong reference to the unmodifiable string representation (used as key) in the value object itself. This would suffice for the object to be only GCed when it is not referenced anymore.

I wonder, is there any way to implement such a cache in typescript?

Comment: Maybe `WeakRef` values in a plain `Map` coupled with a `FinalizationRegistry` as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_management#weakrefs_and_finalizationregistry)?

Comment: This indeed looks very promising. I'll try that ASAP.